# Seperate error messages for required TextFields and DropDownChoices

Tags: wicket

I'm currently working on a Wicket 6.20 project which already has dozens of pages with TextFields and DropDownChoices. Now the requirement came up to change the default `'${label}' is required.` message to something more specific, depending on whether a TextField or a DropDownChoice doesn't have a value.

I know I can put `Required=My Text` in a properties file of the application, but that changes the message for all FormComponents. And specifying the full component path to either the TextFields or the DropDownChoices in the form of `myform.mycontainer.mydropdownchoice.Required=My Text` isn't feasible, since of course the structure of the Forms can differ on each page.

Ideally I'd like to put something like

```
org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice.Required=Please select a value for '${label}'
org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField.Required=Please enter a value in '${label}'
```

in my application's property file, either with or without FQCN.

Is there a way to achieve this with any of the default `IStringResourceLoader` that come with Wicket?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to provide the complete path to the components.  It could be a path with just few parents:

- mycontainer.mydropdownchoice.Required=My Text
- mydropdownchoice.Required=My Text

If this still is not an option then you can override `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent#reportRequiredError()` for any instance or type (e.g. `MyDropDownChoice`).

Comment: Thanks for your input. If the standard IStringResourceLoader implementations don't offer what I need, I'll probably try implementing my own for this special case, rather than replacing each and every DropDownChoice with a custom class.

Comment: Isn't approach 1) what you need ? What would be your solution?

Comment: If i understand approach 1 correctly, then I'd still have to reference each TextField and each DropDownChoice by its Wicket ID in the properties file.Since each page has several TextFields and DDCs, i'd have to go through all pages and add them one by one. All I need is one Required-property for all TextFields and one for all DDCs

Comment: Ok. Custom IStringResourceLoader would be the simplest then.